# Aptana Studio: Treat ASP as PHP?

Tags: macos

I'd like Aptana Studio to open ASP files as if they were PHP (well, ASP would be better, but you take what you can get when you work in obsolete technologies). Also< some files open with the system editor (a totally different editor). How can I change these behaviors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into http://colorer.sourceforge.net/ plugin for Eclispe
https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/questions/251-eclipse-colorer-plugin-to-color-asp-etc

As far as changing editors, it can be done by file extension:

http://www.daveoncode.com/2008/11/24/associate-custom-file-extensions-to-the-default-aptanas-text-editor/

Comment: cool thanks, I'll check both of these out soon. +1 for now.

Comment: In Aptana Studio 3 on OSX, it's preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations.

Comment: for the first part, use this in the update manager for eclipse: http://colorer.sf.net/eclipsecolorer/